# Deleting points in the vector when a condition holds in the other vector

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I am trying to delete points in the matrix, when certain condition holds: 
Lets start with a simple case:

s and v are a vectors both length n:

I want to delete all coordinates in the vector s for which v is equal to zero. 
Lets say s=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] v=[0,0,1,2,3,0,4] The desired result would be 
s=[3,4,5,7]. My try:

```
function[S]=wyj(s,v)  
j=0;
        for i=1:(length(s)-j)
            if v(i)<10^-8
                s(i,:)=[];
                j=j+1;
            end
        end
```

The problem is that j does update, but does not update in the loop... any help appreciated.

Comment: Something like `s(v == 0) = []`?

Comment: wow, thank you!! I didn't know it was so easy.